# Intgrating windows 2000 server in a windows 2008 domain

Tags: windows, windows-server-2000

I have a network enviroment where my windows 2000 server is just acting as fileserver for sharing, so all the users has an account there with username, password and a list of access rights.

Now i want to keep this server  cause i am running from there an application that 20 users access but also i want to add a new Windows 2008 R2 64 bit server as a domain controller. Is this possible ?

1-It is ok to make the new windows 2008 server a domain controller ?

2- I want all the users accounts to be the same in the domain controller so they can still use the same username and password to login into the domain as well into the windows 2000 server that is setup as a Workgroup.

3- Do i need to do something to the windows 2000 sever  to still be functional in the environment so it can be accessed by the clients computers?

note:My clients computers are windows 2000 pro, xp pro and windows 7 32/64 bit.
Thanks in advance

Comment: ...windows 2000 pro? What?

Comment: What you are asking for is a step by step solution on setting up a small business domain network. This is really going to be too much to cover in a single question and if you don't know what you are doing, I would suggest finding a local IT provider that you can work with to help you with setting this up and do some knowledge transfer over to you.

Comment: Is there a reason your hanging on to the Win 2k server vs. moving the file shares over to your new server?

Comment: The only reason is cause the server is still good, in there i have an application which is SBT PRO 5.0 that 20 users are running and since this is a windows 2000 server i don't see why not can be in the forest once the DC is installed but hey i can move the application and the share files to the new server but then i wil have to create a new maps since each workstation that access that server are already mapped to the \\servername\shared folder  but would not be a problem to do that at all thanks for your answer

Comment: Create a DNS alias of your old server name and point it to the new server name.  Then you won't have to create new shares and have to remap everything.  But really, 20 clients is not that big of a deal to remap for.  Unless of course you have dozens of shares...

Answer (score 4):

You're in over your head. About a mile. What you're trying to achieve is not only impractical, it's also impossible. If you want to create an AD domain, everything should be on it, you should not have non-joined servers. Those will be inaccessible at worst, or simply not accepting AD credentials at best. Windows 2000 and XP are seriously ancient (vulnerable to a myriad of new security compromises daily; lacking in management and modern functionality; money-pits) and should be replaced with something newer if you're going to build a domain anyway.

Comment: Well we are not actually able to change all those computers as you mentioned, we cannot do that now, but can you be more specific why is crazy to have an existing windows 2000 server in the same enviroment with windows 2008 server and allow the users to access both servers